# Requisição da API NodeJS

Tags: node.js, api

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta de apenas 1 `id` e ele me retorna um objeto vazio.

Se eu coloco `localhost:8877/jogador/2`, o retorno no console é vazio.

Se eu coloco `localhost:8877/jogador/1`, ele me retorna todo os registros do banco.

O que está de errado no meu Controller?

```
// LISTAR TODOS OS JOGADORES
listJogadores(request, response) {
    database.select("*").table("jogadores").then(apelido => {
        console.log(apelido);
        response.json(apelido);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}

// LISTAR APENAS 1 JOGADOR
listUmJogador(request, response) {
    const id = request.params

    database.select("*").table("jogadores").where({ id: id }).then(apelido => {
        response.json(apelido)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

Arquivo de rotas:

```
router.get('/jogador', JogadorController.listJogadores);    
router.get('/jogador/:id', JogadorController.listUmJogador);
```

Estou usando express e axios.

Comment: _"Se eu coloco localhost:8877/1"_ faltou _"jogador"_ na rota?

Comment: Editei, kkkk. Mas é isso...

Comment: Se eu coloco locahost/jogador/1 ele retorna todos os jogadores cadastrados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partindo do ponto que esteja utilizando **`Express`**, o seu problema aí é que [req.params](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params) como pode ver na documentação, retorna um objeto que contém propriedades mapeadas para os “parâmetros” da rota nomeada. Ou seja, quando faz isso:

```
const id = request.params
```

A constante `id` está armazenando o objeto **params** e não um valor único, no caso aí o seu id. O que te obrigaria a fazer isso para pegar o valor do id:

```
.where({ id: id.id }) // aqui está acessando a propriedade id armazenada em id
```

O correto aí seria pegar a propriedade que deseja e armazená-la na constante:

```
const id = request.params.id; // pega a parametro com nome id
.where({ id: id })
```

Answer (score 2):

Está faltando passar o id para a variável.

Se tiver usando uma versão mais antiga do nodejs seria:

```
listUmJogador(request, response) {
    const id = request.params.id //adicionar este .id

    database.select("*").table("jogadores").where({ id: id }).then(apelido => {
        response.json(apelido)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

ou fazer uma [`atribuição por desestruturação`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
listUmJogador(request, response) {
    const { id } = request.params

    database.select("*").table("jogadores").where({ id: id }).then(apelido => {
        response.json(apelido)
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```